# Serializable a object properties too

Tags: java, serializable, object-serialization

When I have `Serializable` in a class, do I need to add `Serializable` to all my objects within the class?

For example,

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private List<Role> role;
private Task task;
}
```

Do I need to add `Serializable` to `Role` and `Task`, too?

```
public class Task implements Serializable{
    // ...
}

public class Role implements Serializable{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is really easier to ask her that look in specification ?

Comment: also check this , That will be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you do; if your classes `Task` and `Role` are not `Serializable`, you'll get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` if you try to serialize an instance of `User`.

Ofcourse, if `Task` or `Role` contain other non-primitive, non-transient fields, they would have to be `Serializable` too, etc.

Comment: And what about something like this:

Answer (score 3):

That is the simplest option.

The other option is to make those fields tranisent and "override" writeObject and readObject to implement your own serialization for those classes. It is unlikely this is worth the extra effort.

BTW: If you have a nested class, the outer class needs to be Serializable as well as the nested class implicitly has a reference to it even if you don't use it.  For this reason and others I suggest making nested classes `static` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **yes**.
Each object wihtin your serializable class MUST be serializable by itself. Otherwise all properties can't be restored or whatever.

Furthermore, you will also get an exception when trying to serialize this object.

Answer (score 1):

From doc

> Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.

So yes.

[Please read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)